# Sending some byte at time

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to figure out way to send some amount of text from the string ech time until it reach the end of the string, example:

`const char* the_string = "hello world, i'm happy to meet you all. Let be friends or maybe more, but nothing less`"

Output: hello world

Output: , i'm happy to meet you all.

Output: Let be friends or maybe more

Output: , but nothing less

stop: no more bytes to send.

the problem i have searched google, but didn't understand the examples, i spent 4 days trying find a good way, also that sendt 5 bytes at time, but in case there is less, then send them until you are at the end of the string.

please help me out guys, i will accept a C or C++ way, as long it works and well explained.

Comment: Can you clarify how you wish to send the text? Through sockets perhaps?

Comment: Where did the word `more` go?

Comment: I'm going send it over a socket HTTP request that i have made  Shaktal

Comment: Eric, that most be a typo from my side

Comment: Cole Johnson, please help me out instead of -1

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to send only 5 bytes at a time?

Comment: It don't have to be 5 bytes at a time, but just example, just limiter, but in case it under 5 it should send the rest, well until it come to the end. Its more to learn how to do it

Comment: So you just want a way to send a whole string using sockets, basically?

Comment: The socket HTTP request works, but i'm sending small amount of the file eche time, not the whole file once

Comment: If you're using a streaming protocol, such as TCP to send the information, it will be packetized according to the OS TCP/IP stack anyway. Do you want a way to send the entirety of a string/data rather than just sending a little bit of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in C. Hopefully I understood your question.

```
void send_substr(
    const char * str,
    size_t len,
    const size_t bytes_at_a_time,
    void (*sender)(const char *)
    )
/*
   sender() must check the char * manually for
   null termination or call strlen()

   for Unicode just change all size_t to unsigned long
   and all const char * to const wchar_t * (POSIX)
   or LPCWSTR (Win32)
 */
{
  size_t i, index_to_end, tail;

  //for C99 (gcc)
  char ret[bytes_at_a_time];

  //for C89 (Visual C++)
  //char * ret = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*bytes_at_a_time);

  tail = len % bytes_at_a_time;
  index_to_end = len - tail;

  for(i = 0; i < index_to_end; i += bytes_at_a_time)
  {
    memcpy(ret, str+i, bytes_at_a_time);
    *(ret + bytes_at_a_time) = '\0';
    (*sender)(ret);
  }
  memcpy(ret, str+index_to_end, tail);
  *(ret + tail) = '\0';
  (*sender)(ret);
  //for C89
  //free(ret);
}

void print_substr(const char * substr)
{
  while(*substr != '\0')
  {
    putchar(*substr);
    substr++;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  char test[] = "hello world, i'm happy to meet you all."
    " Let be friends or maybe more, but nothing less";
  send_substr(test, sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test), 5, &print_substr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eh, on second thought ret should just go on the stack.

Comment: I fixed `ret` but it will only work with C99 (gcc). If you're using MS Visual C++ (no C99 support), comment out `char ret[bytes_at_a_time];` and uncomment the `malloc()` line as well as the `free()` line (however, the C99 way will work with MSVC if it is a C++ file).

Comment: @user1420741 : "*however, the C99 way will work with MSVC if it is a C++ file*" No it won't; C++ does not support VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

As per the discussion in the comments, I believe what the OP is looking for is a way in which he will be able to send the entirety of data over sockets.

Using C++ and templates, sending arbitrary data over sockets *(for the purposes of this code sample, I will be using WinSock)* is fairly simple.

*General Send Function:*

```
template <typename T>
int                 SendData( const T& tDataBuffer, SOCKET sSock ) 
{
    // Make sure the class is trivially copyable:
    static_assert( std::is_pod<T>::value && !std::is_pointer<T>::value, "The object type must be trivially copyable" );

    char* chPtr = (char*)(&tDataBuffer);

    unsigned int iSent = 0;
    for( unsigned int iRemaining = sizeof(T); iRemaining > 0; iRemaining -= iSent )
    {
        iSent = send( sSock, chPtr, iRemaining, 0 );
        chPtr += iSent;

        if( iSent <= 0 )
        {
            return iSent;
        }
    }


    return 1;
}
```

*Overload for pointers:*

```
template <typename T>
int                 SendData( T* const &ptObj, unsigned int iSize, SOCKET sSock )
{
    // Make sure the class is trivially copyable:
    static_assert( std::is_pod<T>::value, "The object type must be trivially copyable" );

    char* chPtr = (char*)ptObj;

    unsigned int iSent = 0;
    for( unsigned int iRemaining = iSize; iRemaining > 0; iRemaining -= iSent )
    {
        iSent = send( sSock, chPtr, iRemaining, 0 );
        chPtr += iSent;

        if( iSent <= 0 )
        {
            return iSent;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

*Specialization for `std::string`:*

```
template <>
int                 SendData( const std::string& szString, SOCKET sSock )
{
    // Send the size first:
    int iResult = SendData( static_cast<unsigned int>(szString.length()) * sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0'), sSock );

    if( iResult <= 0 )
        return iResult;

    iResult = SendData(szString.c_str(), static_cast<unsigned int>(szString.length()) * sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0'), sSock);
    return iResult;
}
```

An example utilizing these functions would be the following:

```
std::string szSample = "hello world, i'm happy to meet you all. Let be friends or maybe more, but nothing less";

// Note that this assumes that sSock has already been initialized and your connection has been established:
SendData( szSample, sSock );
```

Hope this helps you achieve what you want to.

Comment: Thanks you, thank you alot! just what i need to learn! - sadly i can't pick both, but i give you both +1 and picked, that code that works best

Comment: @user1417815 No problem, glad to help; just make sure you go through the code and understand what each line does, this will help you to learn best! :)

Answer (score 1):

In c++, you may use the substring (substr) method to select part of the string to send. In c, you would have to either iterate through the characters manually, stopping when reaching zero or the desired amount of bytes have been sent, or copy part of the char array to another 0-terminated array and send that.

For example you can send 10 characters at a time like this:

```
string str = randomstaff.from(whereveryoulike);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 10)
{
    destination << str.substr(i, i + 10 < str.size() ? i + 10 : str.size());
}
```

Comment: You may see the usage of substr here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: That dont help me really, in the example they already know what the string contain of words, but in my program its unknow, as it will save the data from a random raw image inside the string...

Comment: That should be no problem. If you want to split the string into pieces of size 10 for example, you may set the start position to i and the end position to the minimum of i+10 and the length of the string (which is also stored in the string). The you iterate i from 0 to the lenght of the string, incrementing by 10 at each step.

Comment: Vincent please show me example, this is not homework, but something i want to learn, please show me how in code.. i'm going accept you right away!

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but only a short code, I'm using my phone.

Comment: Thank you alot, i owe you one! waiting it

Comment: One more comment, this site is not really intended for absolute beginners. If you have just started learning, next time please look a bit more before asking, and try to understand the basics from excellent books and tutorials out there. Otherwise I'm happy to help.